# ASP.Net gridview export to excel in Windows 10

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, gridview, windows-10

I have many instances of code where I am exporting a gridview to excel.  This has been working fine until recently.  I recently upgraded to Windows 10 (same version of excel), and have not been able to get this function to work for any of the pages where it is available. Excel opens, but no sheets.  To confirm my suspicion, I tested on a Windows 7 machine and it worked fine.  Is there a setting I am missing that got set during upgrade?  The code for export is below.

```
Protected Sub ExportButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExportButton.Click
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [MyTable]..."

    Response.Clear()

    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.xls")
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls"

    Dim sw As New System.IO.StringWriter
    Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    GridView1.Visible = True
    GridView1.DataBind()
    GridView1.RenderControl(hw)

    Response.Write(sw.ToString)
    Response.End()
    GridView1.Visible = False
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(ByVal control As Control)

End Sub
```

Comment: Well you aren't generating an actual Excel file, so that's not good. You're making an HTML file that's masquerading as an XLS file. You should be using a library capable of generating real XLSX files.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are not expierence problems due to a Office Upate.

See[excel-2010-kb3115322-opening-downloaded-files](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/excel-2010-kb3115322-opening-downloaded-files/19b8ab42-d0c4-402d-aa79-ad86e191fcc9?auth=1)